# Python site packages installed but not found

Tags: python, pip

I've installed some python packages via pip but when I enter for example `ipython` it returns me the response below and none of my installed packages' executables work.

```
'ipython' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

everything is in the PATH (it recognizes python and pip commands) and I've tried so many ways to fix it but I haven't been successful. I also repaired the python installation but didn't work.

```
> import numpy
> Original error was: DLL load failed while importing _multiarray_umath: The specified module could not be found.
```

> pip install ipython
>
> > Requirement already satisfied

> PATH

```
...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts\
...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\
```

It's been a day I've been struggling with this issue and I have projects to do so any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Where is the ipython executable actually located?

Comment: I think it must be in the site-packages directory. am I right?

Comment: but it's not only ipython, none of my packages work

Comment: I checked the site-packages folder and there is a folder named IPython but I don't know where the ipython executable is

Comment: Have you tried using `venv` for the project?

Comment: no, there is no venv involved and it's the cmd problem

Comment: Is `%APPDATA%\Python\Python39\Scripts` in your PATH ?

Comment: To find the executable do `where ipython.exe` at the command prompt.

Comment: I added `%APPDATA%\Python\Python39\Scripts`  but nothing changed

Comment: I'm working on it to find the ipython.exe and when I enter `where ipython.exe` it returns nothing

Comment: it seems there is no executable file. Is it possible?

Comment: INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s)